# how can we change the directory in linux using perl script after taking input from user

Tags: linux, bash, perl, cd

Hi I am new to Perl and I am trying to change the directory in Linux by call a Perl script
how my script works:
It takes Input from user which directory name they want and then it cd into that directory and perform something.

```
#!/grid/common/bin/perl
 use File::chdir;
 use Cwd;
 print "Directory name \n";
 $dir = <STDIN>;
 $mkdir = `mkdir $dir`;
 print "creating dir";
 $newdir = "$mkdir";
 chdir( $newdir ) or die "Couldn't go inside $newdir directory, $!";
```

P.S I googled before asking this question and I could not find the solution tried chdir, calling bash script in perl none of them worked can you guys please help me.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: Perl has a [`mkdir`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir) function, btw. No need to run an external program. And `mkdir(1)` doesn't normally have any output, meaning your `$mkdir` variable doesn't have anything useful...

Comment: Plus you're not stripping the newline off `$dir` before using it, so you'll get an interesting directory created.

Comment: And always, always, always `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in perl scripts.